# Why might react-router navigate(-1) go back two routes/pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navigation

I've got a page which needs to kick a user back to the previous one if they don't have permissions to view. I made this very simple component as a test but I'm finding that it navigates back two pages not one. Any ideas why?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const GoBack = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [state, setState] = useState('init');

  if (state === 'init') setState('goBack');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state === 'goBack') navigate(-1);
  }, [state]);

  return <p>You are not permitted to view this page</p>;
};

export default GoBack;
```

Comment: It seems you are very likely rendering your app within a `React.StrictMode` component which runs certain lifecycle methods and hooks twice, and double-mounts the component, all to help you debug issues in your code in non-production builds. This [answer](/a/72238236/8690857) may help explain. Otherwise, can you [edit] to clarify what you are trying to accomplish here? This code doesn't seem terribly useful. Are you trying to implement [protected routes](/a/66289280/8690857)?

Comment: Thanks Drew. Second time you've helped out with one of my ill-informed questions. I wfh in a team of one, meaning I have no colleagues to help me form ideas or search terms. protected routes are just the job, thx

Comment: I thought your avatar looked familiar. And no problem, happy to help. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't call setState in the middle of the component's rendering process. This will cause the component to [become impure](https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure). [Strict mode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development) helps you catch this bug early by causing the component to render twice, highlighting the inconsistency. What happened was:

> Component first render -> react see useState("init") -> reach the if
> statement -> setState("goBack") -> the component re-render before
> reaching the `useEffect` ->  rerender -> state is "goBack" -> run the effect
> -> navigate(-1) -> Strict mode makes the component run the second time -> navigate(-1) again.

You can use this to run with and without StrictMode to see the detail:

```
const GoBack = () => {
  // const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [state, setState] = useState("init");

  console.log("before setState:", state);
  if (state === "init") {
    console.log("setState");
    setState("goBack");
  }
  console.log("after setstate:", state);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("inside useEffect:", state);

    if (state === "goBack") {
      console.log("navigate(-1)", state);
      // navigate(-1);
    }
  }, [state]);

  return null;
};
```

Move the if check into the `useEffect` and the problem is gone. If your intend was to prevent users from seeing anything on the screen then you can use [useLayoutEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect)